# What is the difference between these two lines of Objective-C code?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

```
NSArray *emptyArray = [NSArray array];

NSArray *emptyArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

Both of them seem to create empty array. So what's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do a similar thing, but not quite exactly the same thing.

`[NSArray array]` creates an autoreleased array
`[[NSArray alloc] init]` creates an array with a retain count of 1 making emptyArray its owner.

With ARC, you won't notice much of a difference, but with manual memory management you will. If you're using ARC you can probably safely use either, but I'd recommend you stick to one format (I personally prefer to use alloc/init).

Here is an excerpt of [NSArray.m](https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-base/blob/master/Source/NSArray.m) from [GNUstep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNUstep) which follows closely to Apple's Cocoa (formerly NeXT's [OpenStep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStep)):

```
/**
 * Returns an empty autoreleased array.
 */
+ (id) array
{
  id    o;

  o = [self allocWithZone: NSDefaultMallocZone()];
  o = [o initWithObjects: (id*)0 count: 0];
  return AUTORELEASE(o);
}
```

Comment: You may experiance increased memory usage if you rely on autoreleased objects as they will collect in the pool until the nearest pool is drained. If you aren't creating any autorelease pools it won't be released until the end of the current iteration of the run loop.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is how the memory is managed:

```
NSArray *emptyArray = [NSArray array];
```

In this case `emptyArray` is pointing to an **autoreleased** array object, meaning that you don't own the object. But also this means that, if you're NOT using ARC, you can't use this object after the current run loop, unless you increment it's retain count, because it could be destroyed.

```
NSArray *emptyArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

In this case you get an array with a **retain count** of +1. This means that you're responsible for deallocating the memory when you're done using it.

This difference is specially **important** if you're not using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *emptyArray = [NSArray array];
```

is similar to

```
NSArray *emptyArray = [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

This means, `[NSArray array]` returns auto released object. So you do not need to release object created using `[NSArray array]`.

But you are responsible to release object created using `[[NSArray alloc] init]`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically new instances returned from class methods return autoreleased instances which indeed means IOS holds ownership of it and thus no need to worry on releasing it.

`NSArray *arr=[NSArray array];` is same as `NSArray *emptyArray=[[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];`

When using `[[NSArray alloc] init]` if you are using MRC then you are responsible to release while it is taken care automatically for you in ARC.

Hence irrespective of ARC or MRC it is always better to use `[NSArray array]`.